# Angular update dropdown list

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a dropdown(region) that defines what should be shown in the next one(city)

Region.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-region-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './region-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./region-dropdown.component.css'],
  providers: [RegionService, CityDropdownComponent]
})
export class RegionDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  regions: Array<Region>;

  constructor(private regionsService: RegionService, private cityDropDown: CityDropdownComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.regionsService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.regions = data;
    });
  }

  public onChange(value):void {
    console.log(value);
    this.cityDropDown.loadList(value);
  }

}
```

City.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-city-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './city-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city-dropdown.component.css'],
  providers: [RegionService]
})
export class CityDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  cities: Array<City>;

  constructor(private regionsService: RegionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public loadList(regionId: number) {
    this.regionsService.getCities(regionId).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.cities = data;
    });
  }

}
```

city.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="City">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cities" >
      {{city.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

console shows that regionsService returned a list, but the cities list never been updated

Comment: Are you sure returned data is for cities, not for a region?

Comment: CityDropdownComponent in providers?

Comment: @Dhanika yes, maybe it is not right... new to Angular

Comment: @Fka yes, checked that

Comment: @GregoryMazur use a shared service to pass the value in onChange() function. Use shared service and a Subject.

Comment: Try setting the cities variable to an empty list first: cities: Array<string> = []; (in the declaration) It might be that there cant be an onChange() event when there is no object.

Comment: @Dhanika is it an architectural advice or it will solve the issue?  Cause I don`t understand what is the reason of making an additional Observer(SharedService  listens to regionComp and 
CityComp listen SharedService  )

Comment: @Snorre tried to init with a fake object, the fake obj stays

Comment: If you make a StackBlitz with the problem we can try to fix it there. There is no obvious error in your code, but I see that there are some discussion about dynamically changing the mat-select in gihub that might affect you.

Comment: @GregoryMazur It's an architectural advice, it won't solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably need to see your whole project to find out what is wrong, but I have made something similar on this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-wuuknx

It works.

Comment: lol, that is stupid but I transferred the code to regions-component and it works

Comment: here is the my example by the way, just don`t know what to put instead httpClient so it can work locally https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ihgbpg

Comment: Ok, you should probably read up on interaction with components. You had a strange DI of the component that didn't make sense, and you also need to pass input/output to the components using Input and Output directives. Have a look at this fork of your solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whzhuh